# Bacon2D vs Quasi-Engine for QML 2D game development

Tags: qml, qt5

As in topic what is the best 2D QML game engine for develop game using QML, Bacon2D or Quasi-Engine? I initially started to use Bacon2D but the main web site http://bacon2d.com disappeared that it seem the author has abandoned the project. It exist Quasi-Engine also but never tried. Someone with experience in use both engines can suggest what is the best?
Thank you

Comment: I would reccomend [QML Box2D plugin](https://github.com/qml-box2d/qml-box2d) instead.

Comment: Bacom2D work on top of QML-Box2D (is a part of the library package) by additing more features and simplify the develompent.

Answer (score 0):

I reply to myself. Just noted this replay in github repository:

https://github.com/INdT/Quasi-Engine/issues/30

Informing that **all development of Quase-Engine was moved to bacon2d** that mean the author is the same and Bacon2D is the evolution of Quase-Engine. This will reply to my question...